# Responsive jQuery tooltip on hover and focus not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a tooltip script that was created a few years back (2012), the original can be found [here](http://osvaldas.info/elegant-css-and-jquery-tooltip-responsive-mobile-friendly), I've only modified it slightly to this point. To see how I do manipulating its features.

I'm trying to add a focusable input trigger, where a tooltip is triggered on `focusin` on form input elements and a `mouseenter` trigger on all other elements. It seem to be working, until you click outside of the input. There is an undefined issue for some reason with either `targetText.bind('mouseleave', remove_tooltip);` and/or `targetInput.bind('focusout', remove_tooltip);` depending on which is triggered. Where am I going wrong here?

[DEMO (Old)](http://jsfiddle.net/tf76fb7g/2/) - Non-working

[DEMO (New)](http://jsfiddle.net/tf76fb7g/6/) - Working

EDIT(removed js & added working fiddle)

Comment: Shouldn't it be targetsin for focusin event?

Comment: Yes you're right, it's correct in the fiddle though.

Comment: @darcher ... check my answer to see if that's what you're looking for. if not tell me what I am missing

Comment: your answer didn't work, plus there is already a `remove_tooltip` function. I got it working in the "new" fiddle I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Changed your jQuery snippet to the following:

```
targetsin.on('focusin', function(){
    targetInput = $(this);
    tip = targetInput.attr('title');
    tooltip = $('<div id="tooltip"></div>');
    ttip(targetInput);
}).on('blur',function(){
   $(this).next('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

Check [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tf76fb7g/3/)

Comment: There were many more issues than just hiding the tooltip on blur. I adjusted to data-attr because the title started appearing again and was being funky in general. http://jsfiddle.net/tf76fb7g/6/